# How can I "defang" a Doctrine2 Entity?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'd like to create an "API-like" layer in my code that effectively cordons-off database access to higher level code. For example, I might have the following function:

```
class MyApi {
    private $my_user_id;
    function getContacts() {
        $contacts = $em->getRepository('Contacts')->findByOwner($this->my_user_id);
        $em->clear();
        return $contacts;
    }
    function getGroups() {
        $groups = $em->getRepository('Groups')->findByOwner($this->my_user_id);
        //hydrate each group's contacts list
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $group->getContacts();
        }
        $em->clear();
        return $groups;
    }
}
```

I'm using $em->clear() to detach the Entities from the EntityManger before returning them, so my Views can't accidentally modify managed entities. However, I run into problems when I want to compare entities returned by two sequential API functions. Ideally, I'd like a view/controller to contain:

```
$my_contacts = $myapi->getContacts();
$my_groups = $myapi->getGroups();

foreach($my_groups as $group) {
    foreach ($my_contacts as $contact) {
        if ($group->getContacts()->contains($contact)) {
            echo "{$group->getName()} contains {$contact->getName()}!<br/>";
        } else {
            echo "{$group->getName()} does not contain {$contact->getName()}!<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

However, since I detached all of the Contacts from the EntityManager at the end of the getContacts API call, the objects returned by `$group->getContacts()` are *different* PHP objects than those returned by `$api->getContacts()`, so the `contains()` function doesn't work properly.

Do I have any options for "defanging" my entities, making them effectively read-only, without giving up the benefits that the EntityManager provides? (Such as all managed entities representing the same database entry being the same object, being able to further hydrate associated objects after they've been passed back from the API, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you worry that your views are going to make changes that will be committed back to the database?  If your views don't know about the EM (and they shouldn't), any changes they make to the entities will disappear at the end of the request.

The only other option I can think of is to hydrate your results as arrays when they're destined to be fed to the view script.  But that gives up a lot of handy functionality.

Comment: I'm not concerned that my views are going to flush anything themselves, but I am worried about the possibility of a controller calling a "getter" API action, making changes to a returned Entity, then calling a second API action that involves flushing the EM. The second API call will write my intended changes, along with any unintended changes made in between API calls. I could, just _be careful_ not to make changes outside of the API, but the point of the API is to protect myself from mistakes, and free the controllers from having to worry about how the Entities are related to the EM.

Comment: Another option is to detach your entities before passing them to a view. Of course, you'll need to take care that A) You've fetched all associations you need, and B) Your detach operation cascades through all the associations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a little late, but it can be useful for anyone who still needs answer on this issue...

I think there is missing a Domain Driven Design principle here: [Command Query Separation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html).
On every object you can only have two kind of methods:

```
doSomething() {
    //this kind of method can change the internal state
}

getSomething() {
    //this kind of method NEVER changes internal state
}
```

Keeping proper MVC in mind, views should only need get-methods and they can never change a thing.
Detaching you entities is not necessary and no worries are needed, if keeping just CQS and MVC in mind.